# Activity started from notification opened on top of the activity stack

Tags: android, android-activity, notifications

I have an application with multiple activities. On one of them, I set up an alarm. I press the HOME button. When the alarm is triggered, a notification appears. When clicking on the notification, I start a dialogue-like Activity (@android:style/Theme.Dialog). Although I am on the desktop screen, Android opens my last activity and then shows my dialogue-like activity on top of that. I just want to show my dialogue activity wherever the user is.

Does anyone have an idea of what is wrong?

```
Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, NotificationActivity.class);
notificationIntent.putExtra(Constants.EXTRA_ALERT_MESSAGE, contentText);
PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, Constants.PENDING_INTENT_REQ_DIALOG, notificationIntent, 0);
no.contentIntent = contentIntent;
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You probably want to set [`android:taskAffinity`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#aff) and [`android:launchMode="singleTask"`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) in your manifest file for your dialog activity. Setting `taskAffinity` will cause that `Activity` to launch in a separate task with its own stack. The `singleTask` may or may not be completely appropriate for your application but you'll probably want either it or `singleInstance` depending on your use case. You will need to read the documentation to determine which one will work for you.