# Start Activity in a BroadcastReceiver

Tags: android, android-activity, broadcastreceiver

I've built a small app. The only thing it does is, catch an outgoing call and show some activity when it happens. There is just an `Activity` and a `BroadcastReceiver`.

I wanted to integrate my code with another application, I removed the BroadcastReceiver from the `Manifest.xml` and created (and registered) it dynamically from the main activity. My receiver fired well but the activity is not shows up.

**What is the difference between the two methods?**

**How can I make the activity to show up?**

from `MainActivity.java`:

```
callInterceptor = new InterceptOutgoingCall();
IntentFilter callInterceptorIntentFilter = new IntentFilter("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL");
callInterceptorIntentFilter.setPriority(100);
registerReceiver(callInterceptor,  callInterceptorIntentFilter);
```

and from the function `receiver.onReceive(Context,Intent)`:

```
Intent alertIntent = new Intent(context, AlertActivity.class);
alertIntent.putExtra("callnumber", phonenbr);
alertIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
context.startActivity(alertIntent);
```

my activity is declared in the `manifest` like this:

```
<activity android:name=".AlertActivity" 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer at two threads:

1. [Android launch an activity from a broadcast receiver](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4629662/1027400)
2. [Activity started from notification opened on top of the activity stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628246/activity-started-from-notification-opened-on-top-of-the-activity-stack/4628441#4628441)

In the manifest, the activity should be declared with [`android:taskAffinity`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#aff).
And when starting the intent I had to add a flag = [`Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)